# Java: Using TreeSet with a Class type 1

Tags: java

I want to add employee object in TreeSet and want to print object

```
public class DemoTest 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        TreeSet<Employee> list = new TreeSet<Employee>();           
        list.add(new Employee("A",1));
        list.add(new Employee("A1",11));
        list.add(new Employee("A1",11));

        for(Employee e : list)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getName());
            System.out.println(e.getId());
        }
    }    
}
```

Employee class is there
but getting this exception

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Employee cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
 at DemoTest.main(DemoTest.java:14)

Comment: Does your Employee class implement the Comparable interface?

Comment: Ok, apparently it doesn't so either you need to do this, or you can precise a custom comparator when creating your TreeSet. As the doc says _"All elements inserted into a sorted set must implement the Comparable interface (or be accepted by the specified comparator). Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) (or comparator.compare(e1, e2)) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the sorted set. Attempts to violate this restriction will cause the offending method or constructor invocation to throw a ClassCastException."_

Comment: @ZouZou Employee class is not implementing the Comparable interface, Why does we need to implement Comparable interface?

Comment: Because this is the mechanism the TreeSet uses to compare its elements and impose and ordering + the uniqueness. Read the javadoc, it's well explained.

Comment: @ZouZou - That must be an answer :P

Comment: @WhoAmI It has already been answered (see the duplicated question ;) )

Comment: @ZouZou - still you gave a 6 line explaination :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Employee must be `Comparable` :

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    ....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getId(), o.getId());
    }
}
```